# Retrieve an element from a list

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist, rhino

Below is a Rhino JS script code.

User can be provided with below sets of input elements:

**Option 1 (with resend button in UI)**->

```
Index 0 - Enter otp password
Index 1 - Cancel Option
Index 2 - Resend OTP.
Index 3 - Resend OTP to user email
```

**Option 2 (no resend option in UI) ->**

```
Index 0 - Enter otp password
Index 1 - Cancel Option
Index 2 - Resend OTP to user email.
Index 3 - Regenerate OTP
```

How can I map dynamically the user provided value for (Resend OTP to user email) which can be yes/no for the above two options end user is provided with.

I am getting the response from UI as an arraylist.

For option 1, I will need to retrieve value like this .

```
var usrProvidedValue = callResponse.get(3).getSelectedIndexes()[0];
```

For option 2,I will need to retrieve value like this .

```
var usrProvidedValue = callResponse.get(2).getSelectedIndexes()[0];
```

I am not keeping track of which option user is provided with. Can anyone help with a solution on this?

Comment: maybe you could check the size of returned callResponse before doing any sort of getting?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Edited my question. The response size would be identical,challenge is to identify the index of the option (resend otp to user email) for both options 1 and 2.